# Testing whether Pandas dataframe cell contains null value

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a Pandas dataframe that contains two columns that contain either lists of items or NaN values. An illustrative example could be generated using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':['ab','abc','de','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr','stw','stu'],
                       'colB':['abcd','bcde','defg','defh','ghijk','j','mnp','pq','stuw','sut'] })


df['colA'] = df['colA'].apply(lambda x: list(x))
df['colB'] = df['colB'].apply(lambda x: list(x))

df.at[3,'colB'] = np.nan
df.at[8,'colB'] = np.nan
```

... which looks like:

```
        colA             colB
0     [a, b]     [a, b, c, d]
1  [a, b, c]     [b, c, d, e]
2     [d, e]     [d, e, f, g]
3  [d, e, f]              NaN
4  [g, h, i]  [g, h, i, j, k]
5  [j, k, l]              [j]
6  [m, n, o]        [m, n, p]
7  [p, q, r]           [p, q]
8  [s, t, w]              NaN
9  [s, t, u]        [s, u, t]
```

I want to be perform a variety of tasks on the pairs of lists (e.g. using NLTK's jacquard_distance() function) but only if colB does not contain NaN.

The following command works well if there are no NaN values:

```
import nltk

df['jd'] = df.apply(lambda x: nltk.jaccard_distance(set(x['colA']),set(x['colB'])),axis = 1)
```

However, if colB contains a NaN, the following error is produced:

```
TypeError: ("'float' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index 3')
```

I've tried to use an if...else clause to only run the function on rows where colB does not contain a NaN:

```
df['jd'] = df.apply(lambda x: nltk.jaccard_distance(set(x['colA']),set(x['colB'])) if pd.notnull(x['colB']) else np.nan,axis = 1)
```

... but this produces an error:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()', 'occurred at index 0')
```

I've also tried to use the .any() and .all() constructs as suggested in the error but to no avail.

It seems that passing a list to pd.notnull() causes confusion because pd.notnull() wants to test each element of the list whereas what I want is to consider the whole contents of the dataframe cell as NaN or not.

My question is how can I identify whether a cell in a Pandas dataframe contains a NaN value so that the lambda function can be applied only to those cells that do not contain NaN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter rows only for non missing values:

```
f = lambda x: nltk.jaccard_distance(set(x['colA']),set(x['colB']))
m = df['colB'].notna()
df.loc[m, 'jd'] = df[m].apply(f,axis = 1)
print (df)
        colA             colB        jd
0     [a, b]     [a, b, c, d]  0.500000
1  [a, b, c]     [b, c, d, e]  0.600000
2     [d, e]     [d, e, f, g]  0.500000
3  [d, e, f]              NaN       NaN
4  [g, h, i]  [g, h, i, j, k]  0.400000
5  [j, k, l]              [j]  0.666667
6  [m, n, o]        [m, n, p]  0.500000
7  [p, q, r]           [p, q]  0.333333
8  [s, t, w]              NaN       NaN
9  [s, t, u]        [s, u, t]  0.000000
```

Resaon why checking missing values is lists are checked elemetwise:

```
df['jd'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.notna(x['colB']), axis = 1)
print (df)
        colA             colB                              jd
0     [a, b]     [a, b, c, d]        [True, True, True, True]
1  [a, b, c]     [b, c, d, e]        [True, True, True, True]
2     [d, e]     [d, e, f, g]        [True, True, True, True]
3  [d, e, f]              NaN                           False
4  [g, h, i]  [g, h, i, j, k]  [True, True, True, True, True]
5  [j, k, l]              [j]                          [True]
6  [m, n, o]        [m, n, p]              [True, True, True]
7  [p, q, r]           [p, q]                    [True, True]
8  [s, t, w]              NaN                           False
9  [s, t, u]        [s, u, t]              [True, True, True]
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course! Sometimes tunnel-vision sets in and I can't see the easiest solution. Thanks for the (ultra-fast!) response.

Answer (score 0):

It dawned on me as I was writing the question that instead of testing if the content of the cell was not NaN, I could test whether the content of the cell was a list. D'oh! I used the following:

```
df['jd'] = df.apply(lambda x: nltk.jaccard_distance(set(x['colA']),set(x['colB'])) if isinstance(x['colB'],list) else np.nan,axis = 1)
```

This works as required and produces the output:

```
        colA             colB        jd
0     [a, b]     [a, b, c, d]  0.500000
1  [a, b, c]     [b, c, d, e]  0.600000
2     [d, e]     [d, e, f, g]  0.500000
3  [d, e, f]              NaN       NaN
4  [g, h, i]  [g, h, i, j, k]  0.400000
5  [j, k, l]              [j]  0.666667
6  [m, n, o]        [m, n, p]  0.500000
7  [p, q, r]           [p, q]  0.333333
8  [s, t, w]              NaN       NaN
9  [s, t, u]        [s, u, t]  0.000000
```

But jezrael's answer (to filter on NaN beforehand) is probably the most logical approach.

Nevertheless, I would still like to know if there's a way to test for NaN explicitly.